# Rails - merging 2 objects and checking whether the result is NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rails-activerecord

I am adding 2 objects and saving them into a variable, something like this:

```
@articles = Articles.where(...condition1...) + Articles.where(...condition2...)
```

I need to merge these 2 objects this way, there's unfortunately no way write a query that would replace the 2 queries.

Anyway, what's the problem - if the first query contains data, or if the second query returns some data, or if both returns some data, then I can iterate through the data and work with them.

But if none of those 2 query returns data, this is the output of the `@articles` variable:

```
puts @articles.inspect # => [nil, nil]
```

So in the view, if I do something like this:

```
<% if @articles.count > 0 %> # this returns 2
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <div><%= article.id %></div> # error - undefined `id` for nil
```

Why if any of the queries above returns no data, is the result `[nil, nil]` instead of `nil`?

An explanation could be that `@articles` is combine of two queries, but if at least on query returns something, in the output is just `[data]`, not `[data, data]`.

Why is that?

Thank you guys in advance for your time.

Comment: Either it is something I've never noticed or it does not look like you're explictily using `where` statement since `where` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is 'transformed' into `Array` by [to_a](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a) afterwards. Add some code snippet with such query stub.

Comment: @blelump is correct what is happening here? `#where` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object with when combined using `+` will return an `Array`. I feel you must be altering the data in someway because `Articles.where(name: "Does not Exist") + Articles.where(name: "Also Does not exists")` should return `[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
<℅unless article.nil?℅>
    <div><%= article.id %></div> 
<℅else℅>
    <div>no content. </div> 
<℅end℅>
```

The error suggests that the nil class doesn't have a definition for method or attribute id. Use the above snippet.

Comment: Yes, this is a quick fix, however, it doesn't explain why is that.

Comment: + operator is for appending two arrays. So, here, it's just appending the results of your queries. (Nil for both in this case). This would be my best explanation.

Comment: To justify that, try this, [nil] +[nil] = [nil, nil]

Comment: Hmm, but then if there's `nil` and `nil`, the output is `[nil, nil]`, and the `@articles.count` is `2` instead of "desired `0`.

Comment: You can assign the result of both queries to individual variables. Then check if they're both nil before adding. Maybe that can give you a more suitable result you're looking for. Regarding why, will have to dig into it. Will post an update once i find something. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't concerned about the re-iterating over the array, then do "compact!"

```
@articles.compact!
```

after the line in which you assign @articles.

Assuming that @articles will be an array.

If not:

```
@articles = @articles.to_a.compact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two arrays:

```
@articles = [*Articles.where(...condition1...).to_a] + [*Articles.where(...condition2...).to_a]
```

If the two arrays will be `nil`, the result will be an empty array.

Comment: @engineersmnky - `nil.to_a` is `[]`, not `[nil]` so `[*[]] + [*[]] # => []`